# Stripe - how to get the price in the webhook?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

In [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) ,I have created a web hook to be triggered whenever a product is created (i.e. `product.created`). In PHP, I can get the, product ID from the data retrieved through the web hook . But the `default_price` is `null`. I provided the price while creating the product.  My PHP code in web hook follows:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51.......');


$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_.............';


$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];


$event = null;

try {
  $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
    $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
  );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {

  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
  http_response_code(400);
  exit();
}

switch ($event->type) {
  case 'product.created':
    $product = $event->data->object;


echo " product id = ".$product->id;

break;

  default:
    echo 'Received unknown event type ' . $event->type;
}

http_response_code(200);
```

I get the following response in Stripe dashboard for the event:

```
object(Stripe\Product)#12 (19) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(19) "prod_MXdwspfWjwVCAt"
  ["object"]=>
  string(7) "product"
  ["active"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["created"]=>
  int(1664742062)
  ["default_price"]=>
  NULL
  ["description"]=>
  string(25) "Description for demo 3333"
  ["images"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["livemode"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["metadata"]=>
  object(Stripe\StripeObject)#17 (0) {
  }
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "Demo 333"
  ["package_dimensions"]=>
  NULL
  ["shippable"]=>
  NULL
  ["statement_descriptor"]=>
  NULL
  ["tax_code"]=>
  NULL
  ["type"]=>
  string(7) "service"
  ["unit_label"]=>
  NULL
  ["updated"]=>
  int(1664742062)
  ["url"]=>
  NULL
}
```

As you see, the `default_price` is null there.

**How can I get the price ?**

Answer (score 1):

The Dashboard UI likely creates the two objects (Product, Price) separately, and *then* associates the two. In this instance:

1. Product object created first.
2. Price object then created, passing the `prod_xxx` from step 1 to the `product` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-product).
3. The Product object is then updated, setting the `default_price` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/update#update_product-default_price) with the `price_xxx` ID from step 2.

Because of this, the initial `product.created` event will not contain data relating to the associated Price object.

Comment: The product was created yesterday. I am resending the `product.created` request event so many times from the dasboard. Q1) Shouldn't that work Q2) How can I get the price and when  ?

Comment: No, resending the event won't change the payload to reflect the updated Product object. It'll still be reflect the object at the time it was created. You could listen for `price.created` or `product.updated` events.

Comment: When will the `price.created` event be triggered  ?

Comment: Almost ~immediately after `product.created` in the Dashboard flow you described. You'll be able to the the log of events in your [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/events).